# Doubt regarding the likelihood field in measurement model

Tags: ros, particle-filter

[image: likelihood model]

I don't quite understand what **x<sub>z<sub>t<sup>k</sup></sub></sub>**
and **y<sub>z<sub>t<sup>k</sup></sub></sub>**
mean? Are they meant to represent the position of the `kth` laserscan reading? If yes, could someone please help me figure out how are the values of **x<sub>z<sub>t<sup>k</sup></sub></sub>** and **y<sub>z<sub>t<sup>k</sup></sub></sub>** being evaluated? Why isn't the angle of the `kth` laserscan reading (w.r.t. the `base_laser`) being taken into account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my reading is that you're correct that they are indicating the position of the `kth` range result.

They are taking into account with the the angle of each scan through $\theta_{k,sens}$ which is the angle of the `kth` scan relative to the sensor's pose.